# MongoDB - Retrieve only the latest subdocument for each documents

Tags: mongodb

I'm using a collection designed as below:

```
> db.myCollection.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("524ecedecb5603a47a2cc011"),
        "clientId" : ObjectId("524d720d8d3ea014a52e95bb"),
        "hostname" : "paypal.com",
        "inspections" : [
                {
                        "chainId" : ObjectId("524edb0dcb5666fba519c9f8"),
                        "isValid" : true,
                        "date" : ISODate("2013-10-04T15:13:17.634Z")
                },
                {
                        "chainId" : ObjectId("524edb0dcb5666fba519c9f8"),
                        "isValid" : true,
                        "date" : ISODate("2013-10-04T15:15:56.173Z")
                }
        ],
        "name" : "Paypal",
        "port" : 443
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("524edaeecb5624f06c0f2687"),
        "clientId" : ObjectId("524d720d8d3ea014a52e95bb"),
        "hostname" : "google.com",
        "inspections" : [
                {
                        "chainId" : ObjectId("524edb0dcb5666fba519c9f9"),
                        "isValid" : true,
                        "date" : ISODate("2012-09-02T14:27:18.674Z")
                },
                {
                        "chainId" : ObjectId("524edb0dcb5666fba519c9f9"),
                        "isValid" : true,
                        "date" : ISODate("2013-10-04T15:15:56.175Z")
                }
        ],
        "name" : "Google",
        "port" : 443
}
```

And I would like to retrieve, for a given clientId, every entry of my collection, but with only the `inspections` having the latest `date`.

To do it, I'm using this aggregation:

```
db.modules.certificateInspector.sslServices.aggregate(
    {$match: {
        "clientId": ObjectId("524d720d8d3ea014a52e95bb")
    }},
    {$unwind: "$inspections"},
    {$sort: {"inspections.date": -1}},
    {$group: {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "name": {
            "$first": "$name"
        },
        "inspections": {
            "$first": "$inspections"
        }
    }}
);
```

And **it works**.

My only question is: Can we do better (in performance)?
I don't know, I have the feeling that, the $sort thing is pretty heavy.

Thanks!

Comment: "Good enough"? Good enough for what? "Too heavy"? Are the results too large that it will cause the aggregation framework to fail?

Comment: Well, there is not really a "good enough" thing. So I replaced my question by : "Can we do better ?".
Because at the end, the application may have to handle a lot of data (millions / billions). We'll use a distributed scheme but hey, any optimisation is good to take!

Comment: if you are expecting a lot of results, aggregation may blow up: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/

Comment: Other than precomputing/prestoring the values for each client ID, there's not an obvious way to improve this without having access to test data/DB hardware/etc., if those are the results you want. The `sort` and `group` is going to take some time, but if there aren't many documents matched, it's not a big deal.

Comment: Yeah but I'm "afraid of" is that here, I sort EVERY `inspections`. Isn't there a way to sort `inspections` for each `services` ?

Comment: you can check out this simple solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28617676/return-latest-record-from-subdocument-in-mongodb/50382062#50382062